# Paypal php github sample code always error?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am studying the Paypal IPN function which is urgent needed this week.

and i got the sample php code from:
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples

i can actually get a VERIFIED message from sandbox. but in the sample code line 79 starting from

```
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
```

it seems to log error no matter what the response is. and i find $res stores the full response header instead of "VERIFIED" or "INVALID" only.

I do not know if it is my own problem or the code's problem.

i can manage to get the last word in $res in order to make my implementation work, but really would like some experts' explanation. Thanks so much!

```
<?php

// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);

// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);


// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data

if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
// $cert = "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . "\r\n", 3, "./ipn.log");
    }
    curl_close($ch);

} else {
        // Unexpected error occured. We were able to connect to PayPal, but we didn't get INVALID or VERIFIED back. Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req\r\n", 3, "./ipn.log");
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request:". $res ."\r\n", 3, "./ipn.log");
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}

// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req \r\n", 3, "./ipn.log");
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req \r\n", 3, "./ipn.log");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of what it's logging? Assuming you've set DEBUG to true, you should be getting an error in the log file whether it succeeds or not, and the content should be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The Paypal example is a bit clumsy. The do handle the error in the wrong way as you say, but also the way the build the 'echo' from the request is not that efficient.

This is my version. There are a few Codeigniter specifics, but you can use it as an example nonetheless:

```
public function ipn_callback( )
{
    $IPN_url = config_item( 'paypal_ipn_url' );

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Read POST data directly from $_POST causes serialization
    // issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate&' . file_get_contents( "php://input" );

    $ch = curl_init( $IPN_url );
    if ( $ch == FALSE )
    {
        log_message( 'error', "Problems opening IPN url: " . $IPN_url );
        return FALSE;
    }
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_PORT, config_item( 'paypal_ipn_port' ) );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Connection: Close' ) );

    // CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

    // CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
    // of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
    // This is mandatory for some environments.
    // $cert = "./cacert.pem";
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

    $res = curl_exec( $ch );
    if ( $res === FALSE )
    {
        log_message( 'error', "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error( $ch )  );
        curl_close( $ch );
        return;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
    // -------------------------------------------------------

    if ( strrpos( $res, "VERIFIED" ) !== FALSE )
    {
        try
        {
            // call the tnx_type handler, format: $this->ipn_<txn_type>( $args )
            if ( call_user_func_array( array( $this, 'ipn_' . $_POST[ 'txn_type' ] ), array( $_POST ) ) === FALSE )
            {
                throw new Exception( "unsupported txn_type" );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception $e )
        {
            log_message( 'error', "Unhandled IPN: " . $e->getMessage() );
            log_message( 'error', $req );
        }
    }
    else if ( strrpos( $res, "INVALID" ) !== FALSE )
    {
        log_message( 'error', "Invalid IPN: $req" );
    }
    else
    {
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Unexpected error occured. We were able to connect to PayPal, but we didn't get
        // INVALID or VERIFIED back. Log the entire HTTP
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        log_message( 'error', "HTTP request of validation request:" . curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT ) . " for IPN payload: $req" );
        log_message( 'error', "HTTP response of validation request: $res" );
    }
    curl_close( $ch );
}
```

Comment: I considered to use strrpos too. However, is there any chance $res would contain the strings "VERIFIED" or "INVALID" in other field content which will make the validation incorrect?
Now I am using a stupid way to cut $res from last 7 char like this: if (strcmp ($str, "ERIFIED") == 0)